# Kafka upgrade path form 0.10.0.1 to 2.5.0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 5 kafka clusters and one of them runs kafkamirror to consume from the other 4 kakfa and produce for the main kafka cluster.

I've tried the latest version of kafka separately and my apps seems to work fine with the newest version. The upgrade process, as described in the Kafka upgrade https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade is a rolling update, first going to 2.5.0 and maintaining the broker protocol with 0.10.0 and then a rolling restart with the newer protocol

The problem is the mirrormaker and have no downtime in the upgrade process to avoid loss of messages. I've read that consumers should be upgraded first, in this case mirrormaker is producer and consumer at the same time, so I tryed to upgrade my main kafka cluster first and now is running with 2.5.0 with 2.5.0 protocol and the other cluster of my tests it's still on 0.10.0. When I try to initiate the mirror I am getting some warnings/errors because I am still using old deprecated configs:

Which path should I follow to do the upgrade?